# Find unused public and protected methods in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStorm has a handy *unused private method* [inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/code-inspection.html), which detects methods that are without doubt not used.

I would sometimes be interested to scan my project for unused public/protected methods as well. I'm aware that this is not an exact science, and that would report methods that might be used outside this project (in the case of a library, for example), but subject to a manual review, that would probably be very useful.

Is this currently possible with PHPStorm?

Comment: AFAIK it's not currently possible. Related tickets: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1925 ; http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4743

Comment: Good to know it's at least in the to-do list! Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @Benjamin if this feature is important to you, create an account and upvote the issues. Having issues on their issue-tracker is no guarantee that they will be implemented soon, up voting may give it more attention.

Comment: @thaJeztah That's done already :-)

Comment: @LazyOne: the linked article only concerns "unused classes", I found there's a separate issue "global dead code" which sounds more suitable (however it has less activity): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1925

Comment: if you are really desperate, you can go one-by-one clicking methods and/or functions with ctrl. While its far from ideal, its kindda worky if you are for example want to clean up code and can click faster than read&think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was requested previously, and thanfully is possible since PhpStorm 2019.1 EAP #6 (see [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/02/phpstorm-2019-1-eap-191-5849-26/) for details).

[image: unused declaration inspection]

You can create a new inspection profile with only this inspection, and use *Code > Inspect code...* and choose this new profile to find all dead code in your app. Note that this inspection allows you to explicitly set if you want to report fields, methods etc., with what visibility level, and to even set entry points!

Comment: Does anyone understand how the field visibility selector is supposed to work?  You can only pick one specific visibility for each?  Or is it a hierarchy, where selecting "public" also includes protected and private fields?  It's a confusing UI.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible with PhpStorm 6. Here is a snapshot of the Project Settings (where you can set those options):

[image: Project Settings]

Answer (score 5):

**The following only works for private methods.**

It's possible in PHPStorm 7/8.
Go to Code > Inspect Code and use a custom inspection profile.
In the Inspections window, click on Add and unselect everything except PHP > Unused.

**Inspection profile creation:**

[image: Inspection profile creation]

**Inspection scope**

[image: Inspection scope]

Comment: That's only the *unused private method* I mention. My question is about public and private methods that are not covered by versions 7 and 8.

Comment: My bad. I don't think that it's possible for public methods yet.

Comment: @Shaffe it's polite to either remove the answer completely, either add a disclaimer on top of it that this is an incorrect answer (if you feel it's helpful nevertheless).