# Check if a function is used or not (Cleanup of old, grown PHP project)

Tags: php, function, logging

We are in charge of a grown hp project, which has grown over the last 10 years (sic).

There are basicaly a bazillion of funtions used and even more, that are just there for historical reasons.

I am looking for an "intelligent" way now to determine, when a function XYZ() has been called the last time (and if I could also see where this would be perfect).

Doing it manually is an option, but will take ages ... any help / tip is appreciated!

Comment: Any decent IDE (PhpStorm, Netbeans, Eclipse) will give you a "Find Usages" option for functions which will show you every place in your project that function is called.

Comment: @Andy note that this usually won't handle reflection/metaprogramming too well; a code coverage tool may be needed in that case (and even it will fail sometimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Andy wrote in a comment u can use PhpStorm to check if an function is used or not. However this has to be done manually. Right click a function and choose "Find usages". If it isn't used you'll get a message. Sadly i don't have enough reputation to post images to provide a more clear way of explaining.

There is also a code inspector in PhpStorm. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528947/find-unused-public-and-protected-methods-in-phpstorm) for more information. It is explained with pictures.